# Is it possible to find the area of an isosceles trapezoid given only the two bases?

Tags: geometry

I was assigned this as one of the exercises in my programming course homework at college, but I believe this to be mathematically impossible. Am I wrong? Is it possible?

Comment: Given two *adjacent* sides, it is possible. Perhaps that is what they meant.

Comment: assuming only lengths of the bases are given, no. but if bases are given as co-ordinates, then yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example a rectangle is an isosceles trapezoid. The height can be as large as you wish with the bases remaining the same.

Comment: Thank you. I'll notify the professor. Spent quite a while trying to figure this out until I realized it was impossible.